# Отправка email из админ. панели

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

В проекте есть модель обратной связи от пользователя. Вся обратная связь отображается в админке. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы со страницы просмотра обратной связи можно было отправлять письмо пользователю, то есть сделать отдельную форму для этого.

Comment: А у Вас какие трудности возникли? В чем загвоздка?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, могу предложить вариант решения через сохранение модели, раз уж ответы просматриваются через админпанель.
Чтобы отправить сообщение пользователю, открываем его отзыв на редактирование, заполняем поля в конце и сохраняем модель.

P.s. ответ был составлен для данного вопроса, а не взят с готового проекта, поэтому в нём могут быть недоработки. Должно работать. Если что-то не так - прошу поправить в комментариях/предложить правку

#### settings.py проекта

```py
...
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-хост, с которого отправляем сообщения' #Например, smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email-адрес, с которого отправляем сообщения' #Например, user@gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'ваш пароль от почтового ящика'
...
```

#### models.py приложения

(не забудьте выполнить миграции)

```py
from django.db import models

# вместо Feedback - название модели, в которые сохраняются отзывы
class Feedback(models.Model):
    # тут поля вашей модели, в которую сохраняются отзывы. В неё нужно добавить такие поля:
    email_reply = models.BooleanField('Отправить ответ на e-mail')
    email_adress = models.CharField('e-mail адрес для ответа', blank = True, 
    max_length = 500) # если email передаёт пользователь, это поле необязательно. Вместо него можно использовать то, которое уже предназначено для email
    email_reply_capt = models.CharField('Заголовок ответа на e-mail', blank = True, 
    max_length = 500)
    email_reply_text = models.TextField('Текст ответа на e-mail', null = True, blank = True)
```

#### admin.py приложения

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from .models import Feedback

class EmailReply(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.email_reply:
            return
        if not obj.email_reply_text:
            return
        # если для хранения e-mail используется не поле email_adress, а другое - заменяем название. Если оно не строкового типа - приводим к строке
        if not obj.email_adress:
            return

        # сюда можно ещё дописать алгорит проверки, правильно ли введен e-mail
        # впрочем, если адрес окажется некорректным, ничего не сломается. Письмо просто не будет отправлено

        # список получателей (получатели не видят чужие e-mail)
        # если нужно отправлять кому-то ещё, дописываем адреса в этот список через запятую
        # желательно добавить свой адрес электронной почты, чтобы видеть, что вы отправили
        recipients = [
            obj.email_adress, 
        ]

        for mail in recipients:
            try:
                send_mail(obj.email_reply_capt, obj.email_reply_text, 'адрес, с которого отправляем. ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО тот же, что и в settings.py', [mail])
            except BadHeaderError:
                # если есть какие-либо предпочтения в обработке случаев, когда e-mail указан неправильно - описываем обработку таких случаев тут. В моём примере такие адреса просто пропускаются, сообщения отправлены не будут
                pass

        # сбрасываем поля, чтобы при следующем сохранении модели случайно не отправить письмо ещё раз
        # поле адреса электронной почты я не сбрасываю. Вдруг пригодится ещё
        obj.email_reply = False
        obj.email_reply_capt = ''
        obj.email_reply_text = None
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)


admin.site.register(Feedback, EmailReply)
```

Comment: Кст, `not obj.email_reply_text:` и `obj.email_reply_text == ''` одно и тоже, т.к. пустая строка в булевом выражении `False`

Comment: @gil9red утро, не проснулся до конца) подправил, спасибо